# run command taking many arguments with GNU parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a perl program taking two arguments. For example :

```
perl prog.pl -x A -y a
```

I want to use GNU parallel to combine two lists of arguments. For example :

```
perl prog.pl -x A -y a
perl prog.pl -x B -y b
perl prog.pl -x A -y b
perl prog.pl -x B -y a
```

etc...

I tried many syntaxes like :

```
parallel perl prog.pl -x ::: ABC -y ::: abc
parallel perl prog.pl -x -y ::: ABC ::: abc
```

I did not succeed to combine 2 or more arguments.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You are encouraged to walk through the tutorial `man parallel_tutorial` which answers this and other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
parallel --dry-run perlthing -x {1} -y {2} ::: A B C ::: a b c

perlthing -x A -y c
perlthing -x B -y a
perlthing -x B -y b
perlthing -x A -y b
perlthing -x A -y a
perlthing -x B -y c
perlthing -x C -y a
perlthing -x C -y b
perlthing -x C -y c
```

The `--dry-run` just shows you what **GNU Parallel** would do if you ran it.

Comment: Pleasure! Good luck with your project.